# Comentarios fantasma: "mostrar 1 comentario más" no devuelve ninguno

Tags: bug, comentarios, interfaz-de-usuario

Mirando esta respuesta, [¿Como hacer zoom a un JPanel y a sus componentes?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/101678/15855), veo que tiene un comentario nuevo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando haces click, no hay ninguno.

He refrescado la página y sigue saliendo el "mostrar un comentario más".

<sub>Nota: Hay dos comentarios borrados</sub>

---

**Pruebas:**

- He preguntado por el chat y los usuarios que probaron les sucede igual.
- Se reproduce en Chrome, IE y Firefox.
- En la version web movil sale el mensaje pero en la aplicación de Stack Exchange no se reproduce este bug.

---

**Actualización:**

Hace un rato se ha publicado un comentario en la respuesta, haciendo que el bug ya no se reproduzca.

Comment: Parece ser [tag:estado-por-diseño]. En Meta.SE respndieron a [The system sees a comment that doesn't exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44288/209901): _The counts are denormalized so they can be slightly out of sync. This is rare, though_. Habría que ver si sigue así en unas horas, cuando se sincronice. Como siempre, [should I blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: ¿Cuánto tiempo hace que se eliminó cada uno de esos comentarios?

Comment: @fedorqui esperaremos a ver si se arregla. Gracias por los enlaces. Los comentarios fueron eliminados hace 30 min... antes de ver el error.